# The command /pdfpages change the layout of the tables

Tags: pdfpages

I wanted to add a pdf copy of my published paper at the end of my thesis. I used `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, but I found out that the layout of all the tables in the document were changed. I am uploading screenshot from the current layout and a picture I took from a printed previous copy.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\usepackage{chemist,xymtex}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pdfpages} 




\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}

\printbibliography[title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]

\includepdf[pages=-]{paper1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Previous layout:
[image: previous layout]

Current layout:
[image: current layout]

Comment: pdfpages just adds the referenced pdf essentially as an image,  the typesetting of tables in either document can not be affected.

Comment: `pdfpages` simply includes the PDF from `paper1.pdf`. You should show what `paper1.pdf` looks like, not what your printed book looks like. And if your question is about why `paper1.pdf` looks different from the printed book, then you should say how `paper1.pdf` was generated.

Comment: The layout of the tables before the inserted pdf, looked like the 1st picture. After the insertion of the pdf document, the layout of the table is like the second picture..

Comment: pdfpages loads a few package that could have an effect on  other calculations but from your snippet it is impossible to say what happens exactly. Move one table directly behind \begin{document}. If it shows the problem there too, you know that the preamble is the problem and you can make a complete minimal example.

Comment: If I move one table behind \begin{document} I get a lot of errors without a table. When I erase the \usepackage{pdfpages} the tables return to the previous layout..

Comment: Sorry but without real, complete code one needs a very good chrystal ball to guess what your document is doing.

Comment: the bottom table looks to be double spaced so either something has changed `\baselineskip` or `\arraystretch` but this seems unrelated to pgfpages package.

Comment: does the page of the table in your `paper1.pdf` look the same as in the image of the book posted here.

Comment: The paper1.pdf doesn't contain any table. It's simple a pdf from the journal it was published. There are also no page numbers in the pdf that is included in the document.

Comment: i used \includegraphics{paper1.pdf}.. No changes in the layout of the tables but only the 1st page of the pdf was included and in bigger scale that the other document..

Comment: Didn't find any solution, so I covert the pdf into jpeg and insert the pages like figures...